# How to set delay on the client side before redirect?

Tags: php, wordpress, delay

After registering the user and clicking on the sign-up button, a message is displayed to confirm the email on the same page, but the page is immediately redirect and the user does not have enough time to view the message. I want to set a delay (e.g 5 seconds) before the redirect action, and after that, the redirect action will be performed.

```
    if ( is_wp_error($user_id) ){
        throw new Exception($user_id->get_error_message() , 401);
    }

    $data     = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $userdata = QA_Member::convert($data);
    // generate new nonces
    $msg = ae_get_option( 'user_confirm' ) ? __('You have registered an account successfully but are not able to join the discussions yet. Please confirm your email address first.', ET_DOMAIN) : __('You are registered and logged in successfully.', ET_DOMAIN) ;
    $response = array(
        'success'       => true,
        'code'          => 200,
        'msg'           => $msg,
        'data'          => $userdata,
        'redirect'      => apply_filters( 'qa_filter_redirect_link_after_register', home_url() )
    );

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $response = array(
        'success' => false,
        'code'    => $e->getCode(),
        'msg'     => $e->getMessage()
    );
}
wp_send_json( $response );
     }
```

Comment: did you use ajax to receive the data ... If you do so please show ajax code ...

Comment: use sleep(seconds) refer : http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to implement the redirect in JS rather than in PHP. For example you can put this JS code to you ajax callback:

```
window.setTimeout( function(){
    window.location = "PATH_TO_REDIRECT";
}, 100 );
```